# The type or namespace name 'Community' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When I am changing the solution configuration from Debug to Release and solution platform from ARM to x86 or any platform or if I am keeping the same platform as ARM, then I am getting error as  "The type or namespace name 'Community' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" .  Probably this error is because I am sqlite for storing data in offline mode. But How can I reslove this error ??
Please tell me the appropriate way to find the solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you followed the instruction in this [post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18204.how-to-use-sqlite-with-a-windows-phone-8-application.aspx)

In the post there is an instruction that you **add a c++ project** to your solution named **Sqlite**. You get it from github. Admittedly this is very well hidden within the post and is easy to miss.

After including the c++ project to your solution you should add a reference to it from your C# project.

Add reference -> solution -> choose the c++ "Sqlite" project As a reference

After that, and adding the build constant USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE it should work.

Make you sure you set Conditional compilation symbols: `USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE` and release is `x86 or ARM`.

Answer (score 0):

Now, with the new version released for SQLite you just need to add the NuGet Package and after that add the build constant USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE and it will work seamlessly for all the versions including 7.1 , 8.0 and 8.1 SDKs.